# Keras TypeError: One of the inputs does not have acceptable types. LSTM with Ragged Tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to build an LSTM with ragged tensors (the goal is to have an action recognition model that takes in and predicts actions with different length). (using tensorflow 2.6)

the input is shaped like this: <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([  30,   10, 1662], dtype=int64)>, so N sequences of 10 groups of 1662 points.

the model is built like this:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[None, 1662], ragged=True),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences = True, activation = 'tanh'),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences = True, activation = 'tanh'),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences = True, activation = 'tanh'),
    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Dense(64, activation = 'relu')),
    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Dense(32, activation = 'relu')),
    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation = 'softmax')),
])
```

had to use timedistributed layers on dense to match the shape of the ragged tensors, therefore also the output is 3D.

compile and fit:

```
model.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['categorical_accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 4000, callbacks = callb)
```

This code raises an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_23244\613233899.py in <module>
      1 #problem might be due to the timesdistributed that takes in 3d vectors, while the y labels are 2d ones.. look into that
      2 callb = myCallback()
----> 3 model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 4000, callbacks = callb)

~\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1191                 _r=1):
   1192               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1193               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1194               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1195                 context.async_wait()

~\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    883 
    884       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 885         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    886 
    887       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    931       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    932       initializers = []
--> 933       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    934     finally:
    935       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    758     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    759         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 760             *args, **kwds))
    761 
    762     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

~\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3064       args, kwargs = None, None
   3065     with self._lock:
-> 3066       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3067     return graph_function
   3068 

~\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3461 
   3462           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3463           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3464           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3465 

~\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3306             arg_names=arg_names,
   3307             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3308             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3309         self._function_attributes,
   3310         function_spec=self.function_spec,

~\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes, acd_record_initial_resource_uses)
   1005         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
   1006 
-> 1007       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1008 
   1009       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    666         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    667         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 668           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    669         return out
    670 

~\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    992           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    993             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 994               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    995             else:
    996               raise

TypeError: in user code:

    C:\Users\cocco\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:862 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\cocco\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:852 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\cocco\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1286 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\cocco\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2849 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\cocco\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3632 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\cocco\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:845 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\Users\cocco\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:807 train_step
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    C:\Users\cocco\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:460 update_state
        metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
    C:\Users\cocco\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py:88 decorated
        update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\cocco\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py:171 update_state_fn
        return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\cocco\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py:670 update_state  **
        [y_true, y_pred], sample_weight))
    C:\Users\cocco\anaconda3\envs\mediapipe1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py:826 ragged_assert_compatible_and_get_flat_values
        raise TypeError('One of the inputs does not have acceptable types.')

    TypeError: One of the inputs does not have acceptable types.
```

I have only found [this](https://fixexception.com/keras/one-of-the-inputs-does-not-have-acceptable-types/) but it doesn't help much.
I have tried selectively dropping out some inputs to see if there was a problem with the data but it's not. The data are landmarks for motion tracking created with mediapipe.

Comment: What is your prediction Binary or Regreion or Classification ?

Comment: @MUKILANS classification, it's an action recognition model,  I have a set of actions wth different lengths. Every frame I predict the action that that frame represents.